# How to create object of Arrays in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a object of Arrays, how to create it ?

```
const obj = {};
let i = 1;

function* id() {
  while (true) {
    i++;
    yield i;
  }
}

function data(first, middle, last) {
  const arr = [first, middle, last];
  let key = id();
  obj[key.next().value] = arr;
  console.log(obj);
}

data("rohit", "kumar", "sharma");
data("rohit", "kumar", "sharma");
```

I got the correct out but i want to ask is any other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine but it forces you to create only array of three elements.
Here is a code more flexible:

```
const obj = {};

function data(arr) {
  let key = id();
  obj[key.next().value] = arr;
  console.log(obj);
}

data(["rohit", "kumar", "sharma"]);
data(["rohit", "kumar", "sharma"]);
```

I don't know your need but creating an object with incremental value as properties make me think that an array of array would be easier to use instead.

**EDIT**

To simplify everything if you really want to keep an object:

```
const obj = {};
let i = 0;
function data(arr) {
  obj[i++] = arr;
  console.log(obj);
}

data(["rohit", "kumar", "sharma"]);
data(["rohit", "kumar", "sharma"]);
```

If you are ok to use an array, you don't need a function:

```
const arr = [];

arr.push(["rohit", "kumar", "sharma"])
arr.push(["rohit", "kumar", "sharma"])

console.log(arr[0])
console.log(arr[1])
```

Comment: Can we do it without use of generator function

Comment: @SurendraSinghKamboj Replace `key.next().value` with `++i` (if you want to start with 2) or `i++` (if you want to start with 1)?

Comment: @SurendraSinghKamboj why even use the generator function instead of just using a simple variable? `i = 0` and `obj[i++]` is the same but a lot less verbose